# c# MailMessage: Can I control the text in replyto?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailmessage

I am using asp .net and c# (MailMessage object) to send email.  I levereaged the ReplyToList.Add() to specify a different reply to address.  What I am wondering is:

Is there a way to create the mail message ( in the way that I contruct it ) so that if the user actually choses to reply, that there would be a predetermined body text that shows up?  How is this usually done?

Comment: No, thats part of the end users email client that decides what to put in the message

Comment: Exactly. This is not a .NET limitation; it just isn’t supported in the Internet standards for email (RFC 2822/5322).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the earlier commenters explained this is something controlled by the client.

The closest thing that I can think of would be to put a formatted mailto link in the body of an html email, but many mail clients aren't going to process this correctly.

This will work in certain clients, so if you control the audience and you test carefully you might get away with it.